# How can I implement new methodology to improve the response time using case and cross join? the code is below

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, case-when, cross-join

The code below is taking 7 minutes to finish, the code is part of a SSIS ETL transformation step.
There is another way of how can I do it?
The table 1 is comparing with table 2 which is a calendar table.
The SQL Code is below:

SELECT

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_key asc) ID,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.ISHOLIDAY =0
THEN C.ISWEEKDAY  END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2 
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.[DATE_FIELD_4]
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_5 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2 
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_6 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END)-1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_5
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_3 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_5
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_7 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_8
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_7 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_9
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_10
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END)-1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_9 
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_11
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_9
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_12
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3 
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= GETDATE()
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.ISWEEKDAY END)-1 AS 'RESULT...',

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_10
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= CAST(B.DATE_FIELD_8 AS DATE)
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_12
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS RESULT...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= CAST(B.DATE_FIELD_13 AS DATE)
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_10
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END ) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= CAST(B.DATE_FIELD_8 AS DATE)
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_12
AND C.ISHOLIDAY = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END ) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >=B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= CAST(B.DATE_FIELD_13 AS DATE)
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END ) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_14
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_15
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_2
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= GETDATE()
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_15
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= GETDATE()
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_16
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= GETDATE()
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_17
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= GETDATE()
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= CAST(B.DATE_FIELD_18 AS DATE)
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_18
AND C.isHoliday = 0 
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_19
AND C.isHoliday =0
THEN C.isWeekday END)-1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= B.DATE_FIELD_3
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_11
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END) -1 AS result...,

SUM(CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >=B.DATE_FIELD_4
AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_11 
AND C.isHoliday = 0
THEN C.isWeekday END)-1 AS  result...,

SUM (CASE WHEN C.DATE_FIELD_1 >= GETDATE()
    AND C.DATE_FIELD_1 <= B.DATE_FIELD_6
    AND C.DATE_FIELD_20 =0 THEN 1 END)  AS result...

FROM DIM_DATE B
CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE_2 C
GROUP BY Date_Key
order by Date_Key asc
```

Note:
There are 40k records in Dim_date (table 1)
and 7k records in Dim_date 2 (table 2).
There is any funtions that can help me with that in order to reduce the response time?

Comment: Use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Comment: Not much. Do you have an index for `Date_Key`?  Beside that you are doing  a `CROSS JOIN` so you will need do a full table scan of 40k*7k or 280 millions records. So your problem is more probably slow disk or not enough memory. If you include only one `SUM()` on the calculations improve the speed? (My guess is shouldnt improve much)

Comment: Yes date_key has index and the server has 16gb memory 100gb disk

Comment: I'm sure this is over simplifying it and I'm missing something, could you join your date(s) to the calendar table where isHoliday = 0 and then union a second result set to the table where isHoliday = 1 if you need to? I'm not sure I understand the `sum()` aspect of it, seems you could sum using a windowed function after you have your Flag indicating if it is a weekday / weekend / holiday or change the approach slightly.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work...

Comment: Please show your DDL & query plan. [mcve] Please clarify by editing your post, not in comments.